# zpl what's the difference between 200dpi and 300dpi?

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a question. I'm new to ZPL language I used zebra designer to create a label in 200dpi. If I want to make the same label but in 300dpi. What does it change in my zpl code exactly? I was thinking of the dimension, like in

```
^LL799
```

799 will change to another size, but is there anything else?

EDIT:

My goal is to create a C# application to print label on my zebra printers.

The user will choose if it's a 200dpi or a 300dpi and then the right code is sent to GenericText/Only to print on my printer (print to GenericText/Only is required I can't change that). So if you know a way to do that in C# I take it too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer your header question: 100dpi ;-)

Comment: To avoid the inconvenience of having to redesign your label for different resolutions, design it in millimeters to begin with. Put `^MUm` after the `^XA` and `^MUd` before the `^XZ`, and change all your dimensions from dots to millimeters (calculate once manually, use fractional numbers where needed). Then it will print the same on all resolutions. All ZPL commands accept their  sizes in the currently selected units, not in dots. There is one exception though, the legacy `^FB`, that only works in dots and ignores `^MU`.

Answer (score 1):

To switch resolution, the ZPL template needs to change in order for the label to be printed correctly. Basically it's just a matter of scaling by 3/2 for most fields. For example:

```
200dpi          300dpi
--------        --------
^FO40,40    ->  ^FO60,60
^BY4        ->  ^BY6
```

And so on. I coded a converted that does the opposite, just change the multiplier from 2/3 to 3/2 and you should be good to go:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(Converter);

    const string pattern = @"(?<=\^[A-Z0-9]{2,3},?)([0-9]+,[0-9]+)";
    const string input = @" ... ZPL CODE HERE";

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, evaluator));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit...");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string Converter(Match match)
{
    var (w, h) = (double.Parse(match.Value.Split(',')[0]), double.Parse(match.Value.Split(',')[1]));
    var (wNew, hNew) = ((int)Math.Floor(w * 2 / 3), (int)Math.Floor(h * 2 / 3));
    return wNew + "," + hNew;
}
```

This will not convert some fields, such as barcodes. You need to change those manually. You should use http://labelary.com/viewer.html to check the results and adapt. Open 2 viewers and paste 203 and 300 dpi, then select the resolution and label size and compare.

Comment: thanks , i'll try it this weekend ;) just have a question in my zpl there is some variable , for example the value of my barcodes are value that i get from a database much before in my program. they look like that 20210820SE64001 will it be a problem for the converter since there is number in it ?

Comment: No, it won't. The converter works with the regular expression that will only match `xx,yy`, where xx and yy are pairs of values separated by a comma. The data values such as the one you mention will remain untouched (the regex is a little more complex than this but it will leave your values untouched).